# Getting the value from command line input, command-line-args NPM module, node.js/javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use this code to add a -find flag, but I can't find how to get the value in a useable variable.

```
const commandLineArgs = require('command-line-args')
const quicksearch = [
{name: 'find', alias: 'f',type: String}
]
```

I'd like to achieve this in the terminal, -find=github, then use the value of the find flag, in a useable variable, so I can emit it to the server, I've read the docs but theres nothing about it.

Comment: are you ok with `-find github` ie. replace `=` with `<space>` which is the standard repl arg flag syntax

Comment: According to the docs a flag that can have a value, requires an '='.

Comment: As far as I'm aware its with space. Have a look at my answer. I've run it on my machine. it works

Comment: I will try that, must have misinterpreted the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run at the command-promt/bash like:

`node test.js -f github` or

`node test.js --find github` or

`node test.js --find=github`

Expect Output:

`{ find: 'github' }`

Server/Javascript file (*test.js*):

```
var commandLineArgs = require('command-line-args')

const optionDefinitions = [
  { name: 'find', alias: 'f', type: String }
]

const options = commandLineArgs(optionDefinitions)

console.log(options);

//options.find will be equal to 'github'
```

Comment: How can I get the github out from the { find: 'github' }. I originally thought that I could just get its length then just cut accordingly, but is there a better way?

Comment: @Tom its a json object. Pick it up like `options.find`!!

Answer (score 0):

I like the [yargs library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs).

`npm i yargs`

```
//in your script.js

var yargs = require('yargs');
var flag = yargs.argv.nameOfFlag;
//var flag === 'value'

//equivalent to typing this in terminal:
--nameOfFlag value
```

Comment: OP in headine specifically requests `command-line-args`npm module